# How to set the command of View by default with a real filename?

Tags: emacs, latex, tex, viewer

I have this line in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
```

When I type C-c C-c, then View, then the command turns out to be `okular --unique %u`, however, I would like it to be `okular-unique filename.pdf`

Could anyone help? Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should have something like this for your config:

```
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
      '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "okular %o")))
```

I'm not sure if this okular-unique is a program name - it that case just replace okular with okular-unique.

Comment: Perhaps `okular-unique` is an alias on the OP's system.  For me `"okular --unique %o"` works fine.

Comment: I have to retract that.  While `"okular %o"` opens a new okular window every time, `"okular --unique %o"` does not but jumps to page 1 of the opened document on every compilation.  I ended up using `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "true")))` (calling the `true` program, which doesn't do anything) so that I can open the document manually once and then compile using `C-c C-a` without leafing through the PDF every time.